# recursive oracle sql to identify a value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table TABA(PK:NAME) that stores NAME,NAME_TYPE,SOURCE this way:

```
NAME  NAME_TYPE SOURCE
----  --------- ------
Name1 Category  S1
Name2 Category  S2
Name3 Datamart  
Name4 Category  S1
Name5 Datamart
Name6 Datamart
Name7 Category  S3
```

Note above: Only if the NAME_TYPE = Category, then the source is present in the data.

I have another table TABA_PARENT that stores NAME,PARENT_NAME with the relationship between the NAME columns based on the name_type this way.
Datamart to Category relationship is one-to-many.

```
  NAME   PARENT_NAME
    -----  -----------
    Name3  Name1
    Name3  Name2
    Name3  Name4
    Name3  Name5
    Name5  Name1
    Name5  Name6
    Name6  Name7
```

My requirement is to get the SOURCE for TABA where NAME_TYPE = Datamart(currently, it is absent in TABA)

Expected Output:

```
SOURCE column for Name3
-----------------------

S1,S2,S3
```

The trick is to recursively deduce the SOURCE for the Name3 until it maps to a Category in TABA_PARENT.

In the above example:

Name3 is mapped to PARENT_NAME Name1,Name2,Name4,Name5.
3 of these(name1,Name2,Name4) are of name_type = Category and hence the distinct source is available in TABA -- S1,S2
The fourth PARENT_NAME Name5 is a name_type Datamart(source info not available) and needs to be further expanded until it reaches name_type = Category.

We have the information that Name5 is mapped to PARENT_NAME Name1,Name6.
Name1 is a Category and hence source can be deduced.
Name6 is again a Datamart.

But, Name6 ultimately is mapped to Name7 which is a Category, hence source is available -- S3

As shown above, all the mappings have to be recursively resolved until they reach name_type Category to identify the distinct sources.

```
Expected Result: S1,S2,S3
```

I am trying if this can be done using listagg or something similar(small pl/sql code would also be ok, but prefer a sinlge select if possible)
I am having difficulty to recursively do this.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't answer my own question. Hence I am answering in the comment section.

Comment: Thanks for anyone attempting this. 
I tried to use a combination of "connect by" and listagg and achieved the desired result.

    select listagg(source,',') within group (order by source) final_source from ( 
    select
    distinct
    b.source source--,
    from taba_parent a, taba b
    where b.name = a.parent_name
    and b.name_type = 'Category'
    connect by prior a.parent_name = a.name
    start with a.name = 'Name3'        
    );

Comment: Post this as an answer if you're not going to accept one of the other chaps' answers.

Comment: I tried to, but, the website wont allow me to accept my own answer for 48 hours. I will accept my own answer after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for anyone attempting this. 
I tried to use a combination of "connect by" and listagg and achieved the desired result.

```
select listagg(source,',') within group (order by source) final_source from ( 
select
distinct
b.source source--,
from taba_parent a, taba b
where b.name = a.parent_name
and b.name_type = 'Category'
connect by prior a.parent_name = a.name
start with a.name = 'Name3'        
);
```

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments this can be done with a combination of [`listagg()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm), which is available from Oracle 11.2 onwards and [`connect by`](http://psoug.org/reference/connectby.html). If you're not using 11.2 then there are [a number of other string aggregation techniques available](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).

```
select listagg(source, ',' ) within group ( order by source )
  from ( select distinct source
           from taba a
           join ( select parent_name
                    from taba_parent
                   start with name = 'Name3'
                 connect by prior parent_name = name
                         ) b
             on a.name = b.parent_name
                )
```

The `distinct` sub-query is only there because you have multiple sources that are the same. This returns `S1,S2,S3`.

In order to obtain the same for different names you can change the START WITH clause; for instance changing this to `start with name = 'Name5'` returns `S1,S3`.

The fact that a datamart doesn't have a source doesn't matter as you use the hierarchical query on the `taba_parent` table only, joining to the `taba` table only when you have the information you need.

#### Here's a little [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db53d/8) to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks guys.I see the solution provided is the same as what I came up with and all these work.

Answer (score 0):

You need a hierarchical query (connect by) to get your "ultimate parent", then you need to use listagg to concatenate the items together. I only have Oracle 10g, so I don't have listagg. Here's the hierarchical bit:

```
select distinct source from
(
select taba_parent.name, taba_parent.parent_name, taba.source
from
taba_parent
inner join taba on taba_parent.parent_name = taba.name
)
where name in (select name from taba where name_type = 'Datamart')
connect by name = parent_name
start with source is not null
```

This gives:

```
SOURCE
S3
S2
S1
```

And you can use listagg to get S3, S2, S1

Comment: Thanks guys.I see the solution provided is the same as what I came up with before your responses and all these work.